# Broadleaf JUnit Testing Error during loading of ApplicationContext

Tags: junit, broadleaf-commerce

Using Broadleaf 5.2.2-GA edition Multi-Tenant Version

Have added the below source code for JUnit execution:

```
package com.test.simple;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.service.CatalogService;
import org.broadleafcommerce.test.config.BroadleafSiteIntegrationTest;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@BroadleafSiteIntegrationTest
public class JUnitTest {

    @Resource
    private CatalogService catalogService;

    @Test
    public void testInjectionWorks() {
        Assert.assertNotEquals(catalogService, null);
    }
}
```

Completed the required setup added the below details in site pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
    <version>${blc.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
    <version>${blc.version}</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Got the below error as

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not
>   open connection   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
>     ... 71 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
>     ... 76 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
>     ... 81 common frames omitted

**Question 1: Why its should ask for HSQL Driver as I have already configured SQL server both admin and site application as coming up?**

I have added the below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The error is resolved but a new error came up as per below.

> 20:38:56.118 [main] ERROR
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception
>   while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@15bfd87]
>   to prepare test instance [com.bv.test.simple.JUnitTest@52d8ada]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#861d892' of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]
>   while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#861d892': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a2955e7' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a2955e7': Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>     ... 25 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#861d892' of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]
>   while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#861d892': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a2955e7' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a2955e7': Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>     ... 45 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#861d892': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a2955e7' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a2955e7': Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
>     ... 59 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a2955e7' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a2955e7': Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>     ... 69 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a2955e7': Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
>     ... 81 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 86 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: More than one
>   UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id reference in
>     or  elements.  at
>   org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.getUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:54)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 87 common frames omitted

Please help to check how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the cause of your current error is the following excerpt from that stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id reference in or elements.
```

It appears that you have multiple `CachingUserDetailsService` or `UserDetailsService` beans being instantiated. If you look at the source for `UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean#getUserDetailsService` you will see where it verifies there is only one. I would look into your security configuration and figure out why multiple `UserDetailsService` beans are being registered.